# Print array of word lengths not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays

My code is not working as expected. I create an array to track word lengths. For an input, "test test test", I want to output the array: [0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0].

My actual output is: [0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0]

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int c, i, characters;
int word_lengths [10];

characters = 0; //word character count

for (i = 0; i <10; ++i)
    word_lengths[i] = 0;  //initialize histogram

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n'){   //if blank/tab/new line, reset the character count for new word
        if (characters != 0){     //end of word, increment word length count
            ++word_lengths[characters-1];   //array index starts at 0
        }
        characters = 0;
    }
    else {  //inside a word: increment character count
        ++characters;
    }

}
++word_lengths[characters-1];

for (i = 0; i <10; ++i)
    printf("Length of words = %d\n", word_lengths[i]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: since code review is in the title maybe you want to post this on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why are you pre-incrementing everything?

Comment: @Scotty Because pre-incrementing is slightly more efficient than post-incrementing.   "What are you doing wrong?"  Several things. Here's one:  What happens when you hit an 20 character word?  Supercalifragilistic.

Comment: I don't even get the same output as you claim to, I get what you wanted precisely. `./a.out 
test test test
Length of words = 0
Length of words = 0
Length of words = 0
Length of words = 3
Length of words = 0
Length of words = 0
Length of words = 0
Length of words = 0
Length of words = 0
Length of words = 0`

Comment: redirect input userxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't forget to compile your changes? Perhaps you made some code changes and happened to be looking at a previous build.

Comment: yea I think he need to clean build